# undo qsort to return to original data

Tags: c, arrays, sorting

I am using `qsort()` in my program to sort an array so i can use `bsearch()` to find a certain element.

I have the `qsort()` working correctly for the array and as my array is not full at time of sort it returns similar to this

before sort
     `a[0] = value,
      a[1] = value,
      a[2] = NULL,
      a[3] = NULL,`

After Sort
    `a[0] = NULL,
     a[1] = NULL,
     a[2] = value,
     a[3] = value,`

Is there a way to undo the sort to revert to before sort??

this is the `qsort()` code

```
`qsort(a,size_a,sizeof(*value),(int(*)(const void*,const void*)) strcmp);`
```

for comparing the values i am just using `strcmp` because all the values are strings.

Comment: You have to make a copy if you want that.

Comment: Passing `(int(*)(const void*,const void*)) strcmp` to `qsort()` is wrong.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No.  There are multiple original arrays that would sort to the same output array.  How would you know which one to choose?

If you want the original, then you'll need to make a copy, and sort that instead.  (Or alternatively, create an array of pointers to the original elements, and sort that instead.)

Answer (score 2):

While Oli's answer is correct, there is one way around it. If your objects to be sorted have sufficient unused space in them (for example if you make them `struct` type with an extra field of type `size_t`) you can store the original index in the array before sorting them, then perform a second sort operation using this index field as the sort key to put them back in the original order.

Answer (score 1):

Sorting is usually not a reversible transform. Apart from the [Burrows-Wheeler Transform](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Burrows-Wheeler_transform), sorted input, or only one input - I don't think sort is ever reversible.